# NUnit: Dictionary Assert the order

Tags: dictionary, nunit

I am confused about the CollectionAssert.AreEqual for the dictionary. I have the written the following test.

```
    [Test]
    public void DictionaryAssertTest()
    {
        const int count = 2;

        IDictionary<string, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            dictionary.Add(i.ToString(), i.ToString());

        IDictionary<string, string> reversedictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        for (int i = count -1; i >= 0 ; i--)
            reversedictionary.Add(i.ToString(), i.ToString());


        //NOTE: Expecting this to fail but does not
        CollectionAssert.AreEqual(dictionary, reversedictionary);

        //NOTE: When I first convert to List and then pass as parameter it fails 
        CollectionAssert.AreEqual(dictionary.ToList(), reversedictionary.ToList());
    }
```

I am why this does not fail the unit test

```
        CollectionAssert.AreEqual(dictionary, reversedictionary);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple answer: because order of elements in IDictionary (your first assert) is not relevant for AreEqual constraint, but order of elements in IEnumerable (your second assert) is relevant.

Details:

When both arguments are IDictionaries, NUnit uses NUnitEqualityComparer.DictionariesEqual() method to compare your dictionaries. This method checks if those two dictionaries have the same sets of keys (which is true in your case, order does not matter), and then checks if for every key corresponding values are equal.

But when you call .ToList() first, NUnit uses NUnitEqualityComparer.EnumerablesEqual() method to compare your lists of pairs. This method checks if elements in the same positions of both lists are equal, which is not true in your case - pair ("0"; "0") does not equal to pair ("1"; "1")

What can be done if you want Dictionaries to be compared taking order of elements into account? Two ways:

1) Cast them both to lists as you do right now.

2) Implement IComparer interface and pass an instance of it as a third argument into AreEqual assert:

```
CollectionAssert.AreEqual(dictionary, reversedictionary, myComparer);
```

Comment: Your explanation clarifies by question. Thanks.